# IE9 to IE11 object's visible property got changed

Tags: internet-explorer-11

My client wants to test my web application from IE9 browser to IE11and after upgrading my current browser to IE11, I ran my UFT12 scripts but those are getting failed due to object identification issues.
Example, for the same button object in IE9 has visible property = true but in IE11, it has visible false. Please advise what does the problem here?

Comment: Anyone, kindly answer this please

Comment: After a continuous check with microfocus, they clarified that 12.53 doesn't have the patches for solving the mentioned issues and suggested to upgrade it to 12.54 or latest 14.01 version. Now I'm with 12.54 and the issues are gone away.